Opentelemetry- Otel Java agent not exporting System.*, process.*
I am not using actuator/micrometer.
I am looking for metrics apart from JVM under

System.*
OS - process.*
Container

More information is given here on github.com

I don't think the java agent is supposed to send these metrics. That would be responsibility of something like a "node exporter" (where node means machine/VM). Anyway, it's probably best if you keep this question in GitHub, you've already got some answers there from people who know really well OTEL.
